# How to launch adb shell in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 2020.3.1.

I want to launch a adb shell from within Android Studio.

I have the Terminal tab at the very bottom of the IDE.

But I can only open "Local" terminals.

Any ideas where I can launch a "Remote" adb shell?

Comment: refer to this link https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb location of adb is platform-tools folder

Comment: Type `adb shell` ...then press Enter. This will launch a remote shell.

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate adb if it's not already in your executable paths environment variable. The location largely dependent on the OS you use and where you install the Android SDK. In general it's in the `${ANDROID_SDK}/platform-tools/` directory.
2. Execute `adb devices`. This will list the connected adb capable devices. If you are not running any emulators and you only connect your phone then your phone would show up (if not then you may need to treat some permission steps depending on your operating system). Let's say the ID of your device is `XYZ`.
3. Execute `adb -s XYZ shell` and you'll be in a shell on your device.

Comment: adb.exe in folder of windows: `C:\Users\COMPUTER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`

Answer (score -1):

Within you local terminal, you can easily start an adb shell with the command `adb shell`

[image]